# Optimized INSERT of CHILD with MERGE of PARENT

Tags: sql-server, merge, entity-framework-core, ef-core-8.0

I have the following tables: `[ParentTable]` (1..m) `[ChildTable]`. Both have `[Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1)`.

I would like to determine the optimal way of inserting records in the `[ChildTable]` with Entity Framework, without fetching the `[ParentTable]` in memory. More: there many not be a corresponding record in the `[ParentTable]` at the time of the insert into `[ChildTable]`. Ideally, we would do a `MERGE` for the `[ParentTable]` and an `INSERT` into the `[ChildTable]`.

With T-SQL this will look like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @InsertedIDs TABLE (ID INT);

MERGE TOP (1) INTO dbo.ParentTable as Target
USING 
(
  VALUES ('00000000-9F5D-4D3C-9EDC-65BCBEA2D88F', 'Some Description')
) AS Source (TraceId, Description) 
ON Target.TraceId = Source.TraceId
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY Target THEN
    INSERT (TraceId, Description, SomeDateTimeUtc) VALUES (Source.TraceId, Source.Description, GETUTCDATE())
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Target.TraceId = Source.TraceId
        -- this is the match condition, nothing will be changed by the UPDATE
        -- I only do this to bring the record into the 'inserted' special table so I can output the ID
OUTPUT inserted.ID INTO @InsertedIDs; 

INSERT INTO [dbo].[ChildTable] (ParentTableId, SomeMessage, StatusDateTimeUtc)
-- Assumption: only one row will be MERGED into ParentTable at a time
-- So, we will always have only one record in the @InsertedIDs
VALUES ((select top 1 ID from @InsertedIDs), 'Some Message', GETUTCDATE())

select * from ParentTable
select * from ChildTable

ROLLBACK
--COMMIT
```

The above SQL is performing the requested operation in only one trip to the database. I would like to get the same result with Entity Framework.

Constrains:

1. I am aware of the `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);` method. I would prefer to avoid hardcoded SQL in the code.
2. I am familiar with commercial libraries that may help with this (like [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)). These extensions are great and I may resort to them.

**Are there any other solutions?**

I have created a small PoC in GitHub as a quick-start for the code: https://github.com/mpetcov/MergeAndInsert-poc.

I added benchmarks in my code, including one for the `linq2db` solution provided by @svyatoslav-danyliv (Thank you!):
[image]

It is interesting the last 2 benchmarks I ran are showing the `EFCore` implementation to be faster. I was expecting the `Inline SQL` one to be faster and the first series of benchmarks were showing it to be slightly faster. Any thoughts?

Comment: *only one trip to the database* -- In a sense... It's executing two inserts though. EF will also execute two inserts and does so in one query batch. Also, the SQL code is not even near to being really useful in application code. It's not a fair comparison.

Comment: @GertArnold: the SQL code is written to do *only one trip to the database*. Ultimately, I am looking for any code that would accomplish my goal. I will not use inline SQL (nor a Stored Procedure). But, for my education, please feel free to improve on the SQL approach.

Comment: The EF code is also one multi-statement round-trip. There really isn't much of a difference.

Comment: I will try to find a way to simulate the database latency in the benchmarking code so the benchmarks are closer to real-life. Maybe an IDbCommandInterceptor will do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest another extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore), which support `Merge` out of the box. Disclaimer, I'm one of the creators.

With this extensions you can write the following LINQ query, unfortunately it needs two database requests:

```cs
var source = new []
{
    new ParentTable {TraceId = new Guid("00000000-9F5D-4D3C-9EDC-65BCBEA2D88F"), Description = "Some Description"},
};

using var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();

var insertedIds = context.ParentTables
    .ToLinqToDB()
    .Merge()
    .Using(source)
    .On((t, s) => t.TraceId == s.TraceId)
    .InsertWhenNotMatched(s => new ParentTable
    {
        TraceId = s.TraceId,
        Description = s.Description,
        SomeDateTimeUtc = Sql.CurrentTimestampUtc
    })
    .UpdateWhenMatched((t, s) => new ParentTable
    {
        TraceId = t.TraceId,
    })
    .MergeWithOutput((a, deleted, inserted) => inserted.Id)
    .ToList();

context.ChildTables.ToLinqToDBTable().Insert(() => new ChildTable
{
    ParentTableId = insertedIds[0],
    SomeMessage = "SomeMessage",
    StatusDateTimeUtc = Sql.CurrentTimestampUtc
});

transaction.Commit();
```

Extension should generate the following SQL:

```sql
MERGE INTO [ParentTable] [Target]
USING (VALUES
    ('00000000-9f5d-4d3c-9edc-65bcbea2d88f',N'Some Description')
) [Source]
(
    [TraceId],
    [Description]
)
ON ([Target].[TraceId] = [Source].[TraceId])

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
    [TraceId],
    [Description],
    [SomeDateTimeUtc]
)
VALUES
(
    [Source].[TraceId],
    [Source].[Description],
    SYSUTCDATETIME()
)

WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET
    [Target].[TraceId] = [Target].[TraceId]
OUTPUT
    [INSERTED].[Id]
;
```

```cs
INSERT INTO [ChildTable]
(
    [ParentTableId],
    [SomeMessage],
    [StatusDateTimeUtc]
)
VALUES
(
    @ParentTableId,
    N'SomeMessage',
    SYSUTCDATETIME()
)
```

As I mentioned above, two requets are needed. I don't know any extensions may help here to do that in one request.

Comment: Thank you @svyatoslav-danyliv for this solution! This library seems to have the most complete implementation of MERGE I have seen so far in C#. But this is why I added the benchmarks: it seems to be a bit slow. If their underlying mechanism for sending the data to the SQL Server is optimized, I am sure it will be much better in other situations, when bigger collections will be merged. I will definitely check it out for other use cases.

Comment: This function expects a tons of records or reference to temporary table. Will improve speed in upcoming `linq2db V 6.0`.